# some random characters instead of page URls in sitemap

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, yoast

I'm an SEO expert.
I am doing some SEO works on a website but after 3 months I checked site map and see something irregular
my xml sitemap is like this:

```
<sitemap>
<loc>https://zargarbike.com/i24fnwoy.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-05-28T10:05:00-06:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://zargarbike.com/jh1st1ek.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-05-28T03:05:13-06:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://zargarbike.com/odcl0elz.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2023-05-28T10:05:50-06:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
```

what is the problem? and how can I fix it?

my website is on wordpress and I'm using yoast seo plugin. I didn't find my answer nether in wordpress website nor in yoast seo help center. although even by using rank math the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The Yoast SEO plugin will generate sitemaps for custom posts type too, and I think that is what has happened here.

Log in to the dashboard and go to `Search Appearance` under `Yoast settings`.

Under the `Content types` tab it should list all the post types for your website, remove unwanted types by changing `Show in search results` to `Off`  and they should dissappear from the sitemap.